# where are statistics for google chrome extension inline installations?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

i'm using google chrome's inline installation feature for a new extension.  i'm 99% positive it received a ton of installs today, but the number on the chrome web store doesn't appear to be increasing in response.  are statistics held somewhere else for inline installation?

Answer (score 3):

Do your mean the number on the homepage of your extension at the chrome web store?
That should be the number of weekly active users, and is updated irregularly (generally one update per day).

Comment: i guess i'm looking for the number of people who have clicked install, both on the chrome web store, as well as with the inline installation on my web site.

Answer (score 1):

it is a bug in chromium, stats are not accumulated when using inline install

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=327061&q=inline%20installation&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified